# Angular2: Synching two post requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, angular, observable

I have two ajax post request which need to be executed as synchronous calls. 
Scenario is that the form is creating two differnt type of objects, these objects need to be sent to the different API as post request and I have to show animation on the UI until both API returns result to UI.

Any Help!

Edit to add Code

```
  doApproveSingle() {
    //animation part
    this.loading = true
    //call 1
    this._http.post('api/single', this.approvedChanges, contentHeaders).subscribe(resp => { 
    }, error => {
    })
    //call 2
    this._http.post('api/new', this.approveNew, contentHeaders).subscribe(resp => {
    }, error => {
    })
  }
```

there are two post requests I need to close that animation after both calls are completed, need help in that part.

Comment: can you show your code and tell us what is not working so we can help you

Comment: Doesn't sound like this really *needs* to be synchronuous.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: edit done to add code

Comment: you can use es6 promises which will helps you in this case, its fits your requirement.

Comment: but i want to mention that promises are also async, but it will help you.

Comment: The title is misleading. 'synchronously' means that requests should block main thread, and there's no reason to do this in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  doApproveSingle() {
    //animation part
    this.loading = true
    //call 1
    let obs1 = this._http.post('api/single', this.approvedChanges, contentHeaders)
    .map(resp => { ... });
    //call 2
    let obs2 = this._http.post('api/new', this.approveNew, contentHeaders)
    .map(resp => { ... });
    Observable.zip([obs1, obs2]).subscribe(val => this.loading = false);
  }
```

If there is nothing to do when the individual HTTP calls complete, the `.map(...)` parts can be omitted.

Comment: somehow it is not working with map i have to use subscribe to make it work

Comment: Interesting. I'm not using TS myself so I'm not sure about this but if you say so.